# Equivalent construction for old rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I'm not familiar with old version of rspec, now I have to use rspec 1.3.2

I have construction that is built for newest rspec (~> 2.11) which doesn't work on old one:

```
MyClass.any_instance.should_receive(:my_method).with do |id, email, row|
  ...
  row.should be
  ...
end
```

What is the equivalent construction for old rspec version?

Comment: do you have some output when you run the spec? maybe the matchers are different, or the mocking/stubbing part (any_instance)

Comment: `any_instance` is the part missing from RSpec 2.3. Is it possible in your case to know which instance of `MyClass` will receive the method call, and to make it a mock/stub?

Comment: No, it's hidden in the method